# ioredis Key with matching Pattern

Tags: node.js, express, redis, ioredis

I am want to search redis database with key matching pattern 'LOGIN::'. I am using ioredis in my application. yesterday I have searched the whole web and I got few options which are doing this job like as follows :

KEYS

scanStream

**Issue:**

```
import Redis from 'ioredis'

var Client = new Redis()

Client.scanStream <---- Missing
```

scanStream method is missing in Redis instance or if I am doing something wrong then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

so this is the example code that will give you a broad idea. So you can use two things that the redis offers. First is the KEYS function which shouldn't be used due to its O(N) complexity. This example is using the scan command in a stream i.e one by one with different cursor positions.
It will scan the whole redis but will return 10 results at a time which will not stall the redis like the KEYS function would have. We will push all the keys to a keys array after which you can loop through all the keys and use GET command to get value of each key.

```
const redis = require('ioredis');
    let stream = redis.scanStream({
        match: "LOGIN::*",
        count: 10
    });
     stream.on("data", async (keys = []) => {
                        let key;
                        for (key of keys) {
                            if (!keysArray.includes(key)) {
                                await keysArray.push(key);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    stream.on("end", () => {
                        res(keysArray);
                    });
```

Comment: Don't just add code. Add some explanation along with it.

Comment: Duly noted @VishistVarugeese

Answer (score 0):

An example for you.

```js
const stream = redis.scanStream()
stream.on("data", async (keys) => {
  // do what you need
})
```